# Outputting data from table after saving with ckeditor

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, yii2

Am saving data using the `ckeditor` in `yii2` in my form model but when doing the view action it displays the html tags

**CKEDITOR CODE:**

```
<?=  $form->field($model, 'case_description')->widget(CKEditor::className(),[
            'editorOptions' => [
                   'preset' => 'full',
                   'inline' => false, 
            ],
     ]);
?>
```

So after I save the data in the table its saved having the html codes 
example of saved data:

```
<b>My new project being grilled</b>
```

So when viewing the data using `yii2 detail` and `gridview` it always shows  the `<b>` instead of being `bold`.

How can I solve the problem

**EXAMPLE:** of `grid view` outputting it in the `case_description` column

```
<?= GridView::widget([
       'summary'=>"", 
       'showOnEmpty'=>false,
       'dataProvider' => $dataProviderb,
       'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'case_description',
       ],
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the `'format' => 'row'` in your `GridView`  like:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
     'summary'=>"", 
     'showOnEmpty'=>false,
     'dataProvider' => $dataProviderb,
     'columns' => [
          ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

          [
             'attribute' => 'case_description',
             'format' => 'raw',
          ],
      ],
]) ?>
```